# How to show the "timestamp" value from cloud firebase to react native as a date or string?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-native

[image]

Here is the timestamp value I wanna get into my react native app. I can take this as a string and show it like that, but I am asked that it must be a timestamp in the cloud. And possibly take it as date inside the react native project. How do I do this? I can show other fields such as adSoyad, no problem at all.

Also one more thing, how do I show a picture from this cloud system? Here is my app.js by the way:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
Platform,
SafeAreaView,
StyleSheet,
ScrollView,
View,
Text,
Button,
StatusBar,
} from 'react-native';
import firebase from '@react-native-firebase/app'
import firestore from '@react-native-firebase/firestore'
import { format } from "date-fns";
class App extends Component {
state = {
tablo: {
adSoyad: "",
yas: "",
dogumTarihi: "",
mezunDurumu: "",

}
}
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.getUser();
this.subscriber=firestore().collection("tablo").doc
('J6mAav1kjkcjrMupeOqX').onSnapshot(doc => {
this.setState({
tablo: {
adSoyad: doc.data().adSoyad,
yas: doc.data().yas,
dogumTarihi: doc.data().dogumTarihi,
mezunDurumu:doc.data().mezunDurumu,

}
}
)
});
}
getUser= async() => {
const userDocument= await firestore().collection("tablolar").doc
("J6mAav1kjkcjrMupeOqX").get()
console.log(userDocument)
}
render() {
  var mezund;
  var dtarih=toString(this.state.tablo.dogumTarihi);
  console.log(dtarih);
  //this doesn't work though how do we do this??? it gives undefined.
  if(this.state.tablo.mezunDurumu==false){mezund="Mezun Değil"}
  else if(this.state.tablo.mezunDurumu=true){mezund="mezun"}
return (
<View>
  
<Text>Ad Soyad: {this.state.tablo.adSoyad}</Text>
<Text>Yaş: {this.state.tablo.yas}</Text>
<Text>Doğum Tarihi: {dtarih}</Text>
<Text>Mezun Durumu: {mezund}</Text>

</View>
);
}
}
export default App
```

Answer (score 3):

For making your timestamp into a date, try the .toString() method. (If this.state.tablo.dogumTarihi is your timestamp, then this.state.tablo.dogumTarihi.toString()).

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/Timestamp#toString()

You may, however, be better of making it into a Date, .toDate() as seen in the docs linked, and manipulating it's format from there.

As for display an image, you should be using firebase storage for that, not firestore. Look in firebase documentation for pricing and usability reasons for that. What is normally done is a file (such as an image) is stored in firebase storage at some URL x, and x is stored in the firestore so that when you load the document you have access to the  URL at which the image is stored.

Code (copy and pasted from https://dev.to/clintdev/simple-firebase-image-uploader-display-with-reactjs-3aoo) for storing the image and getting it's download URL to store in the firestore document or for use on the page.

```
    storage
      .ref("images")
      .child(image.name)
      .getDownloadURL()
      .then(url => {
        this.setState({ url });
      });

    <img
      src={this.state.url || "https://via.placeholder.com/400x300"}
      alt="Uploaded Images"
      height="300"
      width="400"
    />
```

There is also a react-native-firebase project that might be worth looking into: https://rnfirebase.io/.

This is my first Stack Overflow answer, so let me know if I'm breaking any rules!